# torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder FileNotFoundError: Found no valid file for the classes 0,0.0,1,1.0,10,100. Supported extensions are: .jpg, .jpeg,.png

Tags: image, dataset, transform, torch, torchvision

Tried to load training data with PyTorch torch.datasets.ImageFolder in Colab. But I got this error.

I have uploaded my code here please tell me where my code is wrong. I am try to fix this error but I couldn't.
'''
# Load the dataframe containing the image path and labels

```
WikiCrop_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/wiki_crop/wikiCrop.csv')

#Define the path to the directory containing the images
src_folder = '/content/drive/MyDrive/wiki_crop/'

# Define the path to the train directory
train_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/WikiCrop_TrainDirData'

# Define the path to the test directory
test_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/WikiCrop_TestDirData'

import os

# Create the train and test directories
if not os.path.exists(train_dir):
    os.makedirs(train_dir)
if not os.path.exists(test_dir):
    os.makedirs(test_dir)

#Now, we can create subdirectories in the train and test directories for each label using age and gender information in your data frame:

for age in filtered_df.age.unique():
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(train_dir, str(age)))
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(test_dir, str(age)))

for gender in filtered_df.gender.unique():
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(train_dir, str(gender)))
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(test_dir, str(gender)))

# Split the data frame into train and test sets, with a specified ratio (e.g., 80/20):

train_ratio = 0.8

train_df = WikiCrop_df.sample(frac=train_ratio, random_state=42)
test_df = WikiCrop_df.drop(train_df.index)

# Create the train and test directories
if not os.path.exists(train_dir):
    os.makedirs(train_dir)
if not os.path.exists(test_dir):
    os.makedirs(test_dir)

for index, row in train_df.iterrows():
    src_path = os.path.join(src_folder, row['path'])
    dst_path = os.path.join(train_dir, str(row['age']), str(row['gender']), str(row['path']))
    if src_path != dst_path:
        try:
            copyfile(src_path, dst_path)
        except FileExistsError as e:
            print(f"Error copying {src_path} to {dst_path}: {e}")
    

for index, row in test_df.iterrows():
    src_path = os.path.join(src_folder, row['path'])
    dst_path = os.path.join(test_dir, str(row['age']), str(row['gender']), str(row['path']))
    if src_path != dst_path:
        try:
            copyfile(src_path, dst_path)
        except FileExistsError:
            pass

#train and test data directory
train_data_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/WikiCrop_TrainDirData'
test_data_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/WikiCrop_TestDirData'

import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder

#load the train and test data

train_dataset = ImageFolder(train_data_dir, transform = transforms.Compose([
transforms.Resize((112,112)), transforms.ToTensor()
]))

test_dataset = ImageFolder(test_data_dir, transform = transforms.Compose([
transforms.Resize((112,112)), transforms.ToTensor()
]))
'''
```

After Image Folder I got the error. I have attached WikiCrop_TrainDirData how it look like in my colab.[image]

Please tell me how to solve this error. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and spent at least two hours to fix. If you are using a free colab, you cannot open terminal. thus, type the following in the cell to remove .ipynb_checkpoints. In my example, the root directory is /content/ganface

```
!cd  /content/ganface && rm -rf `find -type d -name .ipynb_checkpoints`
```